# logging different level to different files log4j

Tags: servlets, log4j

I have

```
log4j.rootLogger=wap,err,TRACE
##======================= General Logger ======================== ##

log4j.appender.wap=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.wap.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.wap.File=/tmp/user-info.log
log4j.appender.wap.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.wap.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.wap.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd-MM-yyyy},%d{HH:mm:ss}%m%n

log4j.appender.err=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.err.Threshold=ERROR
log4j.appender.err.File=/tmp/err.log
log4j.appender.err.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.err.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.err.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd-MM-yyyy},%d{HH:mm:ss}%m%n

log4j.logger.com.web.mytest=TRACE
```

I want to log

1) `INFO` information in `user-info.log` file.

2) `ERROR` information in `err.log` file.

with above properties, only err.log file is created and only error information is logged. INFO information and info log file is missing. I am using logging for servlets.

*I want to log for servlets which have both logging for error and info messages.*

How can I fix this?

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes check the FAQ and search for Threshold.

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html

Every appender has a threshold setting that can filter out messages by their level.